# Get home page of the project by artifactId/groupId from Maven repo?

Tags: java, maven

Is there are any instruction or tool to find official home page and documentation for Java module or Maven plug-in which known by Maven **artifactId/groupId**?

pom.xml of Maven project have such info. But if you examine **~/.m2/repository** dir you can't find HTTP URLs, only SHA-sum and **modelVersion/groupId/artifactId/version** components in *.pom file.

General Internet search is painful process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to artifacts deployed on Maven Central, you can search for your artifact with [MVNRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/). If its POM contains a `url` element it will be displayed as a clickable URL.

Comment: But then you have to search the POM for the url element, copy the link and paste it in a browser window. MVNRepository displays the link in the artifact page. By the way, it *is* a front-end to Maven Central.

Comment: search.maven.org displays the pom file also.

Comment: Did you try the two tools and see the difference? Remember, the OP is trying to find a project's home page from its groupId.artifactId